# Take the value without automatically converting it

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a cell that I need to read which has the value **375:00:00**. When looking at the formula I can see that the value is **14.01.1900 15:00:00**. When trying to read the value of the cell I only get the Date and not the 375.

My approach looks like this but I am not sure on how to proceed with converting the cell value?

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
        Dim TimeWB As Workbook
        Set TimeWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="J:\XXX\XXX\XXX\2022\XXX.xlsx", Password:="XXX")
        
        Dim TimeUS As String
        TimeUS = TimeWB.Sheets("Übersicht").Range("E3").Value
    
        'Convert? The given Value (15,625) to back to 375:00:00 ?
    
        'MsgBox Displays 15,625
        MsgBox (TimeUS)
End Sub
```

Is there some kind of built-in function to deal with this? CDate wasn't quite working here.. but I guess this isn't even supposed to be working here.

Comment: You can use the `Text` property of the cell as long as you just want a text value.

Comment: @Rory Thanks! If you could write it as a answer I will be glad to accept it ^^

Comment: That's ok, just accept the one below :)

Comment: Alright then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use

```
TimeUS = TimeWB.Sheets("Übersicht").Range("E3").Text
```

to get it in the same format as the number format of the cell.

Or use the numeric `.Value` and format it to whatever you like:

```
TimeUS = Format$(TimeWB.Sheets("Übersicht").Range("E3").Value, "[h]:mm:ss")
```

---

// Edit

As Rory pointed out `[h]` does only work in `.NumberFormat` but not in `Format()`. Therefore you can use a workaround:

```
Public Function FormatTimeInHoursOnly(ByVal TimeVal As Date) As String
    FormatTimeInHoursOnly = CLng(Int(TimeVal * 24)) & Right$(Format$(TimeVal, "hh:mm:ss"), 6)
End Function
```

And use it like

```
    TimeUS = FormatTimeInHoursOnly(TimeWB.Sheets("Übersicht").Range("E3").Value)
```

Comment: I don't think `Format` understands the `[h]` option. That's an Excel thing.

Comment: The "Text"-Property solution worked perfectly fine for me :)

Comment: @Rory Thanks for pointing out. I've added a workaround for the case using `.Text` is not an appropriate option.

Answer (score 1):

Quite an intriguing case here. Evidently, `15.625` is produced by Excel interpreting this as [h]:mm:ss. `375 / 24 = 15.625`. So, to get back to `375:00:00`, you could just do 15.625 * 24 & ":00:00". When you assign this to a cell, Excel will interpret it as a value, rather than a *string* (but see below...). However, there is something very odd here. You said:

> When looking at the formula I can see that the value is **14.01.1900 15:00:00**.

This is odd. Obviously, it should resolve to **15**.01.1900 etc. I thought you might have made a typo, but apparently not. I've ran some tests:

```
Sub test()

For Each cell In Range("A1:A4")

'Range("A1") = 375:00:00 custom formatting automatically applied: "[h]:mm:ss"
'Range("A2") = 375:00:00 custom formatting manually adjusted: "mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
'Range("A3") = "=VALUE(""375:00:00"")", defaults to general formatting: 15.625
'Range("A4") = "=VALUE(""10000:00:00"")" from 10000 this produces #VALUE! errors (or "Error 2015")

Debug.Print cell.Value
Debug.Print cell.Value2
Debug.Print cell.Text
Debug.Print "---"

Next cell

'''Immediate Window output

'     15.625
'     15.625
'    375:00:00
'    ---
'    1/14/1900 3:00:00 PM
'     15.625
'    01/15/1900 3:00:00 PM
'    ---
'     15.625
'     15.625
'    15.625
'    ---
'    Error 2015
'    Error 2015
'    #VALUE!
'    ---

'''

End Sub
```

So, two very odd things here:

1. `cell.Value` for `Range("A2")` is given as `1/14/1900 3:00:00 PM` (reproducing the quirk in the question mentioned about), even though `.Text` will correctly produce `01/15/1900 3:00:00 PM`.
2. Excel ceases to understand the "logic" at `10000:00:00`. Compare this:

```
Sub insert_convert()

Range("A6") = 10000 / 24 * 24 & ":00:00"    'expected 416.6666667, but now a String: "10000:00:00"
Range("A7") = 9999 / 24 * 24 & ":00:00"     '416.625 (and "2/19/1901  3:00:00 PM" in formula bar)

End Sub
```

I fail to see why these oddities occur. Seem like bugs to me.

---

Edit: I guess problem 2 might have to do with the fact that during the evaluation of `=VALUE("10000:00:00")`, Excel tries to interpret the string as a [`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/date-data-type), and then errs, since:

> [Date h]olds IEEE 64-bit (8-byte) values that represent dates ranging from January 1 of the year 0001 through December 31 of the year **9999**...

Comment: Yes and no. For compatibility with Lotus, Excel treats 1900 as a leap year, even though it wasn't (VBA doesn't). So dates from 1 Jan 1900 up to (but not including) 1 March 1900 are different in value by 1 between Excel and VBA.

Comment: Interesting. So, `.Value` will return a `VBA Date`, because of the formatting. Got it. Always such fun, handling dates!

Comment: What the ... the thought that Excel handles the year 1900 as a leap year never crossed my mind before.. the more you know ^^